# What is the point in decorating a property with the DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Could someone please explain me what the DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey is for?

I am just asking because if I query my table with a particular GSI which C# property has been decorated with this attribute, I still need to pass a DynamoDBOperationConfig that specifies the index name I want to use rather than taking it from the attribute ...

E.g.:

```
var operationConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig
{
   IndexName = "IndexName"
};
```

I am therefore unsure as to what the point is in decorating a property with that attribute.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying which index to use for a query, and specifying which keys make up the index are two completely different things.

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DeclarativeTagsList.html):

> **DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey**
>
> Maps a class property to the partition key of a global secondary
>   index. Use this attribute if you need to Query a global secondary
>   index.

Later, when you make a query, if you want to use the GSI instead of the main table you would only need to set the index name and the mapper will get the key mappings using these annotations.

If you didn't specify `IndexName = "IndexName"` in the query then the mapper would just assume you're making a query on the table itself and not on *one of* the indexes (you could have multiple GSIs at the same time on the same table).